# Wildfly10 (EAP 7) call jboss 5.0.1 EJB without legacy jars

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Dears,

I'm trying to call ejb3 in jboss 5.0.1 from Wildfly 10 or EAP 7.

My code:

```
final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    env.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remoting://localhost:1099");
    env.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", "true");
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
    TestBeanRemote remote = (TestBeanRemote) initialContext.lookup(
"ejb:TestEar/TestBean/TestBean!com.test.TestBeanRemote");
```

but it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:BilllingFacadeCallbackEAR, moduleName:BilllingFacadeCallback, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@3b088d51
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext.requireEJBReceiver(EJBClientContext.java:798)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:186)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.sendRequestWithPossibleRetries(EJBInvocationHandler.java:255)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:200)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:183)
    at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:146)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getActions(Unknown Source)
    at TestStandalone.main(TestStandalone.java:28)
```

Is there any solution to call legacy jboss without old jars?

Answer (score 0):

There is a legacy subsystem for this but I don't know its current status.
https://github.com/jboss-set/jboss-as-legacy

Comment: It is same, it use legacy jars (old jboss client jars) :(

Comment: Since the protocols underneath have changed (JNDI, remoting) I don't see how you could expect for the connection to work without those old jars

Answer (score 0):

The CORBA standard defines an "across the wire" standard for making remote method calls called IIOP or "Internet Inter-ORB Protocol".
You need to set up to use CORBA IIOP in order to make platform independent remote EJB calls.

Therefore, you need to:

1. configure JBoss 5 so that it can handle incoming IIOP calls;
2. configure WildFly 10/EAP 7 to make outgoing EJB invocations using IIOP.

There is some information on this in the [WildFly 10 EJB3 Reference Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/EJB+3+Reference+Guide) although I'm not sure how up to date that is.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is normally caused by a transaction reaching it's timeout value.

So it may be that the application logic is correctly handling the scenario in this case and is not attempting to retry activity

It can have several issues :

- connection: Connection broken
- security : user/pass invalid
- EJB missing: connected, but ejb is not there
- SSL
- Ports
- IP Address

JBoss maintains a persistent connection to the other server, so when the client sees this message it means there is no connection to a server that has the ejb you are trying to call, so a message will be logged when the connection fails to the other server.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling

Can you clarify the below:

1# is your EJBs deployed on  jboss 5.0.1?

2# You are invoking the EJBS from Wildfly 10 or EAP 7, means your client is deployed in Wildfly 10 or EAP 7?

Comment: #1  Yes it is deployed. I have sucessfully connected it with legacy ejb client libraries

 Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
  properties.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

#2  I'm invoking the EJBs from Eap 7

Comment: The issue has been occurred due to the below reasons, check  :                                                          - Connection broken
- security : user/pass invalid
- EJB missing: connected, but ejb is not there
- SSL
- correct Ports 
- correct IP Address